# Threading: does c# have an equivalent of the Java Runnable interface?

Tags: c#, java, interface, multithreading

Does c# have an equivalent of the Java Runnable interface?

If not how could this be implemented or is it simply not needed?

thanks.

Comment: Big thanks to everyone who answered this amazing response.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Nope. C# handles threads differently to Java. Rather than subclassing the Thread class, you simply create a new System.Threading.Thread object and pass it a ThreadStart delegate (this is the function where you do the work)..

Comment: Side note: in Java, the `Runnable` interface is an alternative to subclassing `Thread`, but you still have to create a new `Thread` object, passing the `Runnable` to a constructor.

Comment: So basically, ThreadStart *is* the exact C# equivalent to Java's Runnable.

Comment: @Michel Borgwardt: Yeap, the answer is correct ( in essence ) but wrong in the way is it written.

Comment: Runnable has NOTHING to do with threads. The way people use it has a LOT to do with threads.

Comment: Runnable, in and of itself, has NOTHING to do with threads. The way people use it has a LOT to do with threads.

Runnable is an interface that defines a void run method. There is nothing about Runnable that requires threads be involved.

You can, for example, have a set of observers on an object which are nothing but Runnables that get  their run() method invoked every time the observer needs calling. I know this may seem a tad contrived but, for a large number of use cases, it is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 59):

> *Does c# have an equivalent of the Java Runnable interface?*

Yes, it's [ThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx)

```
class Runner
{
    void SomeMethod() 
    {
        Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
        newThread.Start(); 
    }

     public void Run() 
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Running in a different thread.")
     }
}
```

Would be equivalent to the following Java code

```
 class Runner implements Runnable {

     void someMethod() {
        Thread newThread = new Thread( this );
        newThread.start(); 
      }

      public void run() {
          out.println("Running in a different thread.");
      }
  }
```

Comment: As of 2015-09-25 this has yet to be implemented for Xamarin, so you're stuck with Frankenstein C#/Java options to accomplish the same thing as this answer.

Answer (score 15):

The [`ThreadStart` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart%28VS.80%29.aspx) is essentially the same as the `Runnable` interface.  A delegate is like an interface for a single method rather than an entire class, so it's actually easier to implement than the `Runnable` interface in Java.

MSDN [explains about delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> Delegates and interfaces are similar
>   in that they enable the separation of
>   specification and implementation.
>   Multiple independent authors can
>   produce implementations that are
>   compatible with an interface
>   specification. Similarly, a delegate
>   specifies the signature of a method,
>   and authors can write methods that are
>   compatible with the delegate
>   specification. When should you use
>   interfaces, and when should you use
>   delegates?
>
> Delegates are useful when:
>
> - A single method is being called.
> - A class may want to have multiple implementations of the method
>     specification.
> - It is desirable to allow using a static method to implement the
>     specification.
> - An event-like design pattern is desired (for more information, see the
>     Events Tutorial).
> - The caller has no need to know or obtain the object that the method
>     is defined on.
> - The provider of the implementation wants to "hand out" the
>     implementation of the specification to
>     only a few select components.
> - Easy composition is desired.
>
> Interfaces are useful when:
>
> - The specification defines a set of related methods that will be
>     called.
> - A class typically implements the specification only once.
> - The caller of the interface wants to cast to or from the interface
>     type to obtain other interfaces or
>     classes.

Answer (score 6):

`C#` uses the `ThreadStart` delegate instead of Java's `Runnable` style.

```
public class Foo 
{

   public void DoStuff()
   {
      while (true)
      {
         // do some stuff
      }
   }
};

public class Bar
{
    public static int Main()
    {   
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        // create a ThreadStart delegate and pass in the method that will run 
        // (similar to run on Java's Runnable)
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(foo.DoStuff));
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not needed - threads in C# take an instance of a `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate which are the runnable components of the thread to execute.

Answer (score 4):

The closest to a high level task-oriented threading API would be a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). As others have mentioned, .NET (and thus C#) use delegates for representing a callable method. Java doesn't have that concept (function pointers), and instead uses interfaces for callable objects.

Answer (score 3):

.Net uses the `ThreadStart` and `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegates to bootstrap Threads.

Delegates being first-class citizens in .Net, you can keep a reference around if you need to.