# c# Anonymous Interface Implementation

Tags: java, c#, interface, anonymous

i've already seen this question a few times but i still don't get it.
In Java, i can do this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}).start();
```

In my opinion, this is a very nice way to implement interfaces which implementations are only used once. Is there a way to do this in C#?
I've already heard of delegates, but that only solves the problems partly since i can only implement one method. What is the "right" way to do that in C# if i have multiple methods? Do i have to implement another class for that?

Thanks in Advance!
-Chris

EDIT:
I don't want to make a new thread specifically. That was a more general question about the right way to do something like an anonymous implementation from Java in C#. It's not about that specific example.

Comment: *Is there a way to do this in C#?* - Nope.

Comment: Use `ThreadStart` delegate for `Runnable` implementation (related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923512/threading-does-c-sharp-have-an-equivalent-of-the-java-runnable-interface)). Note that C# doesn't have support to anonymous interface implementations, you need to create concrete class and define all methods there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general way to do this is C# is to create your own private class. As you noted, other approaches in C# (delegate/lambda) only work when the interface has just one method (i.e., a Java functional interface):

Java:

```
void testMethod()
{
    x = new ISomeInterface(){
        @Override
        public void method1() { foo(); }
        @Override
        public void method2() { bar(); }
        };
}
```

C#:

```
void testMethod()
{
    x = new ISomeInterfaceAnonymousInnerClass();
}

private class ISomeInterfaceAnonymousInnerClass : ISomeInterface
{
    public void method1()
    {
        foo();
    }
    public void method2()
    {
        bar();
    }
}
```

Here is the simplest conversion when a Java functional interface is involved:

Java:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ISomeInterface
{
    void method();
}

void testMethod()
{
    x = new ISomeInterface(){
        @Override
        public void method() { foo(); }
        };
}
```

C#:

```
delegate void ISomeInterface();

void testMethod()
{
    x = () =>
    {
        foo();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you've searched this before and by now the answer is: **No. Noway in C#**
But I think your main question is **Why?**

**Short Answer:** It **can** be designed in the next C# versions as a feature. It's absolutely **possible**.

**Long Answer:** If you want more details on why it's not added to the C# yet; there is a helpful conversation below this exact **feature request** in the [Roslyn (an open-source .Net complier)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) page at GitHub. Check it out: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13